# JavaScript Pop-Up When User Navigates Away

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

My below code for a JavaScript pop-up works very well for my Visualforce page. However, when I click on my save button I also receive the pop-up, which I don't want in my case.

How do I modify the below code so that it shows the pop-up when I click anywhere except my save button?

```
var evt = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var checkEvt = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';
evt(checkEvt, function(e) { 
    var msg = 'Are you sure you want to leave the page?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;
    return msg;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a blog post [here](http://michaelwelburn.com/2013/04/08/confirming-a-user-really-wants-to-leave-a-visualforce-page/), that suggests using variables to handle this, so you would only show the message when your variable is false. Clicking the save button would set this variable to true in order to bypass your message screen.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">              
    var tempDisableUnload = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if(!tempDisableUnload){
            return confirm("You have made changes to this form. Do you want to continue without saving these changes?");
        }
        return;

    }    
    function setDisableUnload() {
        tempDisableUnload = true;
    }                             
</script>  
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" onclick="setDisableUnload();"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!Account.external_id__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: this is not working at all..i have pasted the same code in my script tags.. :(

Comment: @NehaPatil I edited answer with code that I tested out on my Dev org and this is working for me.

Comment: i dont know why its not working for me..i tried the same code  :(

Comment: @NehaPatil Which part doesn't work? What browser are you using?